# If I make my application with the Zend framework, will I be able to host it with any company that supports PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, hosting

Thank you for the answers. :)

I'm mainly looking to host my website with A Small Orange, but they don't say if they support Zend anywhere. :S

Comment: Really? Close? How is this not programming related? Make your case.

Comment: It would fit better on Server Fault, since it's a question about hosting, not about how to use the Zend Framework API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this list](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFUSER/Zend+Framework+Web+Hosts#ZendFrameworkWebHosts-NorthAmerica), A Small Orange is compatible with Zen Framework.